# A subscript must be between 1 and size of array ERROR (Crystal Reports)

Tags: crystal-reports, report

What might be the problem with this code?

```
**WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar Array myTotal;
myTotal[UBound(myTotal)];**
```

Answer (score 1):

In Crystal Reports, the array indexes start at 1. So, you'll need to use `UBound(myTotal) + 1`